# LinkedIn login integration in AEM

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, linkedin-api, aem

I am trying to integrate login via LinkedIn in my AEM website, but i could not find any well explained solution/process over web. Facebook/Twitter were simple as they come out of the box.

I found this link https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-communities-oauth-sample which is a code that seem to enable this, but how this will work is not very clear.

If you can redirect to a blog post or help me with the process of actually implementing LinkedIn login, that will be of great help!

To add, I am completely new in server side of AEM, i have worked on creating components and templates but never on server side for AEM. This sample is in Java, which is again new to me. How to integrate and make it work is a challenge i am facing.

Comment: If you're new to server-side development in AEM and Java and OAuth and LinkedIn's API/configuration, it sounds like you're biting off a lot at the same time… Maybe pick a programming language that you're more familiar with (JavaScript?) and first of all get a sample JS<->OAuth integration working, e.g. following a tutorial on NodeJS/OAuth2 integration. Once you have that, you should hopefully grasp how OAuth works generally and can adapt it to use the LinkedIn API. From there, you have a working implementation that you can port to Java, and finally make configurable within AEM.

Answer (score 0):

You need an AEM authentication handler and use OAuth library, There is an article on StackOverflow which can help you in creating OAuth library.
[LinkedIn API Authentication using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232697/linkedin-api-authentication-using-java)